# angular.min.js XMLHttpRequest cannot load file

Tags: angularjs

[![

```js
/* app.js */

var model = angular.module('app',['ui.router']);

model.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
 
 $stateProvider
 
 .state('home',{
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'view/home.html',
  controller: 'homeController'
 })

});

/* home.js */

model.controller('homeController',function($scope){

});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller/app.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller/home.js" ></script>
 </head>
<body ng-app="app">
<header>Jayesh Shelar</header>
<div id="view" ui-view> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3hPI.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3hPI.png)HI

I am getting error as "angular.min.js:103 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: Use webserver. Don't use file:/// protocol.

Comment: do i need to use webserver like tomcat, wamp etc to run angularjs ?

Comment: Yes. However it's not about Angular, it's about stricter web-security policies browsers impose these days. You need to use http:// protocol. Any webserver will work for your purpose: Apache, Tomcat, or very simple npm packages like [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) or even simple python server run from terminal `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `npm install http-server -g` and start the server in your project folder by using `http-server` command.

Answer (score 1):

Re-start Chrome with the command line option
    --allow-file-access-from-files

For security reasons, you might want to have a separate shortcut to start Chrome for local debugging with that command line option.